# Unique set of MKAnnotations

Tags: swift, mkannotation, hashable

So what I'm trying to do is to update the annotations on a `mapview`, but I want to put them into a Set first so to check for existing, new and removed annotations. I'm having some checking for conformance of the Hashable `protocol` because of this

> Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

Any ideas on how to do what I want

```
var set: Set<Hashable> = Set()
for annotation in self.annotations {
     guard let hashable = annotation as? Hashable else { continue }
     set.update(with: hashable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what i ended up with is this

```
let newHashValues = Set(new.map{ $0.hash })
let existingHashValues = Set(self.annotations.map{ $0.hash })

let removedHashes = existingHashValues.subtracting(newHashValues)
let addedHashed = newHashValues.subtracting(existingHashValues)

let removed = self.base.annotations.filter({ removedHashes.contains($0.hash) })
let added = element.filter({ addedHashed.contains($0.hash) })

self.removeAnnotations(removed)
self.addAnnotations(added)
```